# Erro - Python 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have the error of the topic title, can you help me?

```
while (True and not False):
    print('''
    +-------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                  CRUD - Python com SQLite3                  |
    | 1. Create                                                   |
    | 2. Read                                                     |
    | 3. Update                                                   |
    | 4. Delete                                                   |
    | 5. Criar Tabela                                             |
    | Use os comandos do SQLite3!                                 |
    | Input < 1 and > 5. Sair                                     |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------+
    ''')
    input = input('Selecione uma opção: ')
    if input == '1':
        sql = input("Digite o comando para INSERIR: ")
        inserir(sql)
    if input == '2':
        sql = input("Digite o comando SELECT:")
        select(sql)
    if input == '3':
        print('0')
    if input == '4':
        print('0')
    if input == '5':
        sql = input("Digite o comando para criar tabela: ")
        sql = criarTabela(sql)
    else:
        exit(0)
```

Thank you
Whenever I run the error appears in the line of:
 sql = input ('blablabla')

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7nMD.png)

Comment: You should use another name for `input = input`. Here you overwrite the `input` function with the actual input.

Comment: And FWIW, that `while` condition is weird.

Comment: your `if` could be `elif` (except for the first one)

Answer (score 1):

You write a line:

```
input = input('Selecione uma opção: ')
```

But that will **overwrite the `input` function**: now `input` will point to the string you have entered. And you cannot call a string.

You should **rename the variable**, for instance using `foo`:

```
while True:
    print('''
    +-------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                  CRUD - Python com SQLite3                  |
    | 1. Create (Inserir dado em uma tabela)                      |
    | 2. Read (Select, lista os dados de uma tabela)              |
    | 3. Update (Atualiza uma tupla ou um atributo)               |
    | 4. Delete (Remove uma tupla de uma tabela)                  |
    | 5. Criar Tabela                                             |
    | Use os comandos do SQLite3!                                 |
    | Input < 1 and > 5. Sair                                     |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------+
    ''')
    foo = input('Selecione uma opção: ')
    if foo == '1':
        sql = input("Digite o comando para INSERIR: ")
        inserir(sql)
    if foo == '2':
        sql = input("Digite o comando SELECT:")
        select(sql)
    if foo == '3':
        print('0')
    if foo == '4':
        print('0')
    if foo == '5':
        sql = input("Digite o comando para criar tabela: ")
        sql = criarTabela(sql)
    else:
        exit(0)
```

Comment: Could you please give an example, if you will not disturb you?